# org.postgresql.*; class not found error

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, copy

I am using Java with eclipse.
I downloaded postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar and added it. (Properties-> Java Build Path-> Libraries -> Add External JARs...

My Database connection is working just fine I can create tables, execute queries ect. 
Now I want to use the CopyManager. And therefore added to my code:

```
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager;
...
CopyManager cManager = new CopyManager(XXX);
```

unfortunately I get an error Message saying: "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file CopyManager.class"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.<init>(CopyManager.java:46)
at Table.insert_data_in_tb(Table.java:73)
at DB.main(DB.java:69)
```

I'd be very thankfull for any help...

Comment: "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file CopyManager.class" does not seem like any runtime error to me. You probably clicked F3 on the CopyManager or its method. Also the error you are seeing is because maybe you are passing NULL to init?

Answer (score 1):

This is a message you get while running your code and clicking methods in debug mode. To correct the immediate problem (being able to view the source code) do this:

- Download [PostgreSQL 9.1 source
  code](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-jdbc-9.1-901.src.tar.gz)
- Copy the file to some appropriate folder and untar it

  `tar xvf postgresql-jdbc-9.1-901.src.tar.gz`
- Add the source folder to your debug configuration in Eclipse
  (Run->Debug Configurations->select Java Application->Click Source
  tab->Add->File System Directory->add ), where directory is
  where you expanded the tarball too.

However, you really don't need to view the source code in order to determine whats going wrong in your program. The documentation for `CopyManager` is available in [online Javadocs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). The constructor for the object requires a valid connection, which I am guessing is null in your program.